# I have a question regarding graphing a function

Tags: calculus

Find an example for $f(x)$ that is defined on the interval $(-1,5)$ is continuous everywhere except at $x=0,1,2,3,4$ and has no limit at $x=0,3$. I am completely lost any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: are you looking for an example of such f(x)?

Comment: You don't ask anything

Comment: I mean how would I graph this? sorry about that

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful.

Comment: By "$x=0,3$" do you mean a point _in the plane_ (on the y-axis, three units above the x-axis), or the number $\frac{3}{10}$? Or perhaps that your function has no limit for $x\to 0$ and also has limit for $x\to3$?

Comment: @garmischgang123 Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Here is a graph one such function.

[image]

It is defined everywhere on (-1,5) and not defined at the endpoints.

It has a jump discontinuity at (0,3). This means that the limit does not exist at this point.

It has removable discontinuities at the other points, making the function discontinuous at those points, but limits nonetheless exist.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

- $\frac 1 {x-a}$ is continuos, not defined only for $x=a$ and has not limit for $x\to a$
- $\frac 1 {(x-a)^2}$ is continuos, not defined only for $x=a$ and has limit for $x\to a$

see for example [HERE](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fx%2B1%2F(x-1)%5E2%2B1%2F(x-2)%5E2%2B1%2F(x-3)%2B1%2F(x-4)%5E2-20%20from%20-1%20to%205)

[image]